# How can I trap clicks on location for calendar events

Tags: android, calendar

I would like to create an app which interfaces with calendar events such that I could redirect taps on the location link for a calendar event and point them to my app for more information.  Could anybody point me in the right direction for the necessary api calls and or issues I'll need to deal with.  Ideally, one would tap the location link and be presented with a choice of using google maps or my app to present the location information instead of just automatically being directed to maps.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Figure out what `Intent` is used for the event you want (e.g., is it `ACTION_VIEW` with a `geo:` `Uri`?)

Step #2: Set up your `Activity` with an `<intent-filter>` that will respond to that `Intent`.

Bear in mind, though, that it is *very* unlikely that you will *only* be able to handle requests from a calendar app. More likely, anything on the device that launches a map will cause your app to be an option.

Comment: Excellent, this is exactly the kind of foot-in-the-door info I was looking for, thank you!  Makes sense regarding the scope of what events would be captured but this shows me how to get started.  Thanks.